# jQuery get data not accessible as an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, get

I get this result from a jQuery GET request, but it isn't seen as an object.

```
[{
    "amount": "19323",
    "image_tag_id": "1",
    "language_iso": "en",
    "image_tag": "bla",
    "image_content_id": "1",
    "image_id": "1",
    "last_change": "2010-08-18 09:46:53",
    "description": "bla presented by a hairy fly",
    "title": "bla_presented_by_a_hairy_fly",
    "alt_text": "bla presented by a hairy fly"
}]
```

This is the result I get.
I need the amount to be shown on the page.
But now if I would get it as an 'imagecount' result and ask an `imagecount.amount` or `imagecount[0].amount` it is undefined.

```
echo json_encode($results); //gives the results

 $.get('/file.php', imageSearchData, function(imagecount) {
   $('.imageAmount').html(imagecount[0].amount);
 });
```

Call to the file.

Comment: You may be getting the JSON as a string. If this is the case then you will need to run `JSON.parse` on the JSON string.

Comment: Try JSON.parse(imagecount[0].amount)

Comment: Use `$.getJSON` to have the string deserialised for you automatically, or make sure you set the right `application/json` response type in the headers of your PHP. Are you building the string manually in your PHP code, ie using concatenation? If so you should really change this to use `json_encode()`

Comment: Most things worked! What I have now is a sendContentType('application/json') in my php. So I only have to do it once and use it for more query's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal `$.get`, gets a json string. Try using `$.getJSON` where it already parses the json object.

```
 $.getJSON('/file.php', imageSearchData, function(imagecount) {
   $('.imageAmount').html(imagecount[0].amount);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're encoding your data in the server side you should parse it in client side before use, so you could do that using **[`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/JSON/parse)** or **[`$.parseJson()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/)** :

```
$.get('/file.php', imageSearchData, function(imagecount) {
      imagecount = JSON.parse(imagecount);
      //OR
      //imagecount = $.parseJson(imagecount);

      $('.imageAmount').html(imagecount[0].amount);
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use `JSON.parse()` to solve this.

```
 $.get('/file.php', imageSearchData, function(imagecount) {
   var imagecountParsed = JSON.parse(imagecount);
   $('.imageAmount').html(imagecountParsed[0].amount);
 });
```